# Updating an object in Javascript with new values

Tags: javascript

I initially have an object test, which has some values. Inside test there is a variable called someContent. It is initially empty.

I have a list of keys, for which I need to find the values from a different service.

I store the list in my test object. Once I get the response in myResults, is there a way for me to store the results again in test, which has the values for the keys. If value isn't present I would like to know and get it as "N/A"

The output I am expecting is:
var test = `{x:10, y:10, results: {"B": 45, "C":30, "D": "N/A"}};`

One way would be to loop through the entire list, and update test. Is there a better way?

```js
var test = {
  x: 10,
  y: 10,
  someContent: []
};
var list = ["B", "C", "D"];
test.someContent = list;
var myResults = {
  "B": 45,
  "C": 30
};

console.log(test)
```

Comment: There is no JSON here, only JavaScript. You're misusing the term "JSON".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this? Use an object instead of an array

Using the list as key

```js
var test = {
  x: 10,
  y: 10,
  results: {}
};
var list = ["B","C","D"];
var myResults = {
  "B": 45,
  "C": 30
};
for (var i=0;i<list.length;i++) {
  test.results[list[i]]=myResults[list[i]] || "N/A"; // only update if there is a value
}

console.log(test)
```

Using the results as key - initial list has N/As

```js
var test = {
  x: 10,
  y: 10,
  results: {"B":"N/A", "C":"N/A", "D":"N/A"}
};

var myResults = {
  "B": 45,
  "C": 30
};
for (var res in myResults) {
  test.results[res]=myResults[res]
}

console.log(test)
```

Comment: should you not do `test.someContent.push(list)` ? it will turn the array into an object, unless you want it to become an object

Comment: nice, better now

Comment: I upvoted I don't know who downvoted. Some hater probably

Comment: @mplungjan How do I convert a normal array to the form you created

Comment: @mplungjan you modified my original var list

Comment: Micro optimization of for loop:
for (var i=0, l=list.length;i<l;i++) {

Comment: I only do that for longer arrays or arrays of unknown length.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
    var list = ["B", "C", "D"];
        
        var myResults = {
          "B": 45,
          "C": 30
        };
    
    var test = {
          x: 10,
          y: 10,
          results: {}
        };
        
      list.forEach(function(v) {
            test.results[v] = myResults[v] || "N/A";
   
      });
        
        console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this.

```js
var test = {
  x: 10,
  y: 10,
  someContent: []
};
var list = ["B", "C", "D"];
test.someContent = list;
var myResults = {
  "B": 45,
  "C": 30
};
test.result = list.map(function(element, index) {
  return myResults[element] || 'N/A';
});
console.log(test);
```

Comment: That does not do what OP asked

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) here.

Here we iterate over the array in `test.someContent` and set the value of `test.results[key]` to either the value of the corresponding `myResult` property if the key is *also* in `myResults`, or 'N/A'.

```
test.results = test.someContent.reduce((p, c) => {

  // If the element is a key in myResults return the value, or N/A
  p[c] = (c in myResults) ? myResults[c] : 'N/A';
  return p;

// Pass in an initial empty object for test.results
}, {});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/bwbc8sdc/)**

Comment: This will fly completely over OP's head

Comment: OP asked if there was a better way. I think this is a better way, carefully explained. And I didn't have to make stuff up to get my code to work with the OPs code either.

Comment: If something is unreadable and not understandable by the audience, it is not a better way in my opinion

Comment: Why? It is a community. You link externally instead of keeping the code here where it does not suffer link rot. I wanted to see the code here instead of jsfiddle

Answer (score -2):

Just add results to test like so:

```
test.results = {"B": 45, "C":30, "D": "N/A"};
```

Or if it comes in from a variable:

```
test.results = myResults;
```

Comment: I dont get results with N/A